# Dealing with heteroscedasticity when dependent variable is already log-transformed

Tags: regression, residuals, heteroscedasticity, fitting

I have already log-transformed the dependent variable but there is still `heteroscedasticity` in the residual-fitted plot. What one usually does in situations like this? My current regression technique in linear regression.
[image: Fitted vs residulas]

The data I am experimenting with is from a Kaggle competition: [Santander Value Prediction](https://www.kaggle.com/c/santander-value-prediction-challenge)

Comment: Would you please post a link to the raw "un-transformed" data?

Comment: If you have not yet done so, I suggest adding an offset term to the fit.

Answer (score 1):

1. you could try other transformations. In R, https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/boxcox.html looks for an optional power transformation
2. If you can't remove the heteroscedasticity by a suitable transformation, you have to fit a model that accounts for changes in the variance. In R, this can be done with the weights option in the gls function.